# How to scope a method call within a module

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activesupport-concern

- I want to define a method encapsulated module.
- It has the same name as a method in a different module.
- When calling the one I want it calls the other one that is mixed in first.

Code :

```
class User
  include ModuleA
  include ModuleB
end

module ModuleA
  extend ActiveSupport::Concern

  included do
    def hi
    end
  end
end

module ModuleB
  extend ActiveSupport::Concern

  def hi(param)
  end

  def say_hi
    hi(param)
  end  
end
```

Errors with

```
ArgumentError: wrong number of arguments (1 for 0)
# ./app/models/concerns/modulea.rb:16:in `hi'
```

Rails 4

Comment: Why is `ModuleB` not using the block form of `included`?

Comment: @MichaelKohl: The real question is, why `ModuleA` is using that form :)

Comment: Short answer: remove the name clash (that is, rename one of the `hi` methods). As long as it's there, _something_ will be broken (either ModuleA or ModuleB, depending on which you include first)

Comment: @SergioTulentsev My humble attempt at http://www.wikiwand.com/en/Maieutics failed ;)

Comment: @MichaelKohl: haha, it appears so :)

Answer (score 3):

The correct answer would be to remove included in both the Modules.
Instance methods will happily be included without the included block. as suggested by @Sergio Tulentsev

```
class User
  include ModuleA
  include ModuleB
end

module ModuleA
  extend ActiveSupport::Concern

  def hi
  end
end

module ModuleB
  extend ActiveSupport::Concern

  def hi(param)
  end

  def say_hi
    hi(param)
  end
end
```

Comment: Frankly speaking I would go with @Sergio Tulentsev. That is renaming of clashing method names.